# How to draw a line on panel overlapped by other panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

IDE: visual studio, c#, Windows from application

I am trying to draw a line on a panel. I am able to draw line on panel1 by clicking on it.

```
//Code  

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int px=5, py=5;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 5, 5, px, py);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        initilizeXY(e.X, e.Y);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void initilizeXY( int pxx, int pyy)
    {
        px = pxx;
        py = pyy;           

    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       panel1.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        initilizeXY(e.X, e.Y);
    }
}
```

// by this code i am able to draw a line on mouse down on panel 1.

but due to some requirement changes there is another panel ( panel2) which is partially overlapping panel1.

Now i want to draw the same line on panel1 if the user click on panel1 or panel2.

Please suggest how make this work done?

Comment: So you want the line to continue from panel1 to panel2?

Comment: yes, I want, because on panel1 there is small panel panel2, I want if i click on panel2 i want same functionality (line drawn) (continuous line) over panel2.

Comment: This i believe involves some math. Find the intersect point between your line and the panel2. Then draw the two lines. There may be an easier solution but i can not think something else right now

Comment: Overlapping controls is normally a problem, the one on top overlaps and obscures the one on the bottom.  But not for Panel, and a few other pure .NET controls that don't wrap a native Windows control, you can simply set the second panel's BackColor property to Color.Transparent.  As long as its Parent is the overlapped panel, it won't work when the parent is the form.  If that's the case then *do* consider just not using Panel controls at all and simply use the form's Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed the code to work properly.
Tested in a scenario when panel2 overlaps panel1 on the right side of panel1, starting a little lower than panel1's top.

Writing this bit of code I assumed panel2's X and Y coords are greater than panel1's. Perhaps you should reverse the offset calculation if it's the other way around.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int px = 5, py = 5;
    static int p2x = 0, p2y = 0;
    int offsetX;
    int offsetY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        offsetX = panel2.Location.X - panel1.Location.X;
        offsetY = panel2.Location.Y - panel1.Location.Y;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 5, 5, px, py);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        initilizeXY(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void initilizeXY(int pxx, int pyy)
    {
        px = pxx;
        py = pyy;
    }

    private void initilizeXY2(int pxx, int pyy)
    {
        p2x = pxx;
        p2y = pyy;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Refresh();
        panel2.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        initilizeXY(e.X+offsetX, e.Y+offsetY);
        initilizeXY2(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (px > offsetX && py > offsetY)
        {
            int p2start = findIntersectFromLineEquation(new Point(5, 5), new Point(px, py));

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, p2start - offsetY, p2x, p2y);
        }
    }

    private int findIntersectFromLineEquation(Point start, Point end)
    {
        if (start.X == end.X || start.Y == end.Y)
            return 0;

        double a = (double)(end.Y - start.Y) / (double)(end.X - start.X);
        double b = (double)(start.Y) - (double)(a * start.X);

        return (int)(a * offsetX + b);
    }
}
```

Remember to subscribe the events accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
Point bgn1 = new Point(5, 5);
Point end1 = new Point(5, 5);
Point bgn2 = new Point(0, 0);
Point end2 = new Point(0, 0);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pnt, pntscr;

    pnt.X = 5;
    pnt.Y = 5;

    pntscr = Panel1.PointToScreen(pnt);

    bgn2 = Panel2.PointToClient(pntscr);
    end2 = bgn2;
}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    end1.X = e.X;
    end1.Y = e.Y;

    Point pntscr;

    pntscr = Panel1.PointToScreen(end1);

    end2 = Panel2.PointToClient(pntscr);
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Refresh();
    panel2.Refresh();
}

private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    end2.X = e.X;
    end2.Y = e.Y;

    Point pntscr;

    pntscr = Panel2.PointToScreen(end2);

    end1 = Panel1.PointToClient(pntscr);
}

private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Refresh();
    panel2.Refresh();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, bgn1, end1);
}

private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, bgn2, end2);
}
```

valter